# Unable to decode QPSK

Tags: qpsk

[image]

I am trying to decode QPSK data and these are the constellation and timing plots, what could be the reason for the non convergence of QPSK constellation

Comment: My first guess would be lack of symbol synchronization.

Comment: carrier frequency offset, symbol timing offset and likely both

Comment: I am using an OOT model from the transceiver for decoding. The data fed is a iq file captured from SDR and is feeding directly to the Receiver OOT model. In that case hoe to account for these offsets?